# HERE Maps: Adding Layer Dynamically in MapSettingsControl

Tags: overlay, here-api

Add layers in MapSettingsControl dynamically so that I can toggle there visibility. 
When I tried to add layer in mapSettingControl It was disabled.

**Background:**

I have a web app developed using leaflet. I have 5 layers as shown in figure-1. Its working fine in leaflet. Now I am using HERE Maps javascript API for developing same web app.

**How I did in Leaflet:**

I add them as map overlays when adding layer control i.e.

```
let layerControl = L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

while when I need to add overlay in layer control dynamically I use following:

```
layerControl.addOverlay(somelayer, "layer name");
```

This work fine.

[image: showing layer control in leaflet: figure-1]

**How I am doing by using Here Maps js api:**

As I have five layers, two are cluster layers while two are marker layer and one geojson. 
I have tried to apply same approach by creating GROUP for five layers and adding them into the layers of  map setting controls.

```
  public clusterGroup1 = new H.map.Group();  
  public clusterGroup2 = new H.map.Group();
  public markerGroup1 = new H.map.Group();
  public markerGroup2 = new H.map.Group();
  public boundary = new H.map.Group();
```

created customized map setting ui :

```
this.customizedMapSetting = new H.ui.MapSettingsControl({
      baseLayers: [{
        label: "Normal", layer: defaultLayers.vector.normal.map
      }],
      layers: [{
        label: "Cluster-1",
        layer: this.clusterGroup1
      },
      {
        label: "Cluster-2",
        layer: this.clusterGroup2
      },
      {
        label: "Marker-1",
        layer: this.markerGroup1
      },
      {
        label: "Marker-2",
        layer: this.markerGroup2
      },
      {
        label: "Geojson",
        layer: this.boundary
      }]
    });
    this.customizedMapSetting.setAlignment('top-right');
    ui.addControl("customized", this.customizedMapSetting);
```

[image: Heremap mapsetting]

I am adding markers to a group like this:

```
dataArray.forEach(data=> {
            let lat = data.latlng[0];
            let lng = data.latlng[1];
            var marker = new H.map.Marker({ lat: lat, lng: lng }, { icon: icon});
            this.markerGroup1.addObject(marker);
          });
```

**Problem Statement**
I am unable to get this mapSetting ui working for my layers.

How can I add clusterlayers in MapSettingControl so that I can toggle (show/hide) them?  (I think I am not using right approach of group) *When I add them as a map.addLayer(clusterLayer) it work fine.*

How Should I add layer dynamically in MapSettingControl? Possible alternative of leaflet method :

```
layerControl.addOverlay(somelayer, "layer name");
```

Comment: please provide a minimal and relevant code snippet to understand the issue and what did you achieve so far.

Comment: Hi, do you want to display some bitmap image on HERE Map? Then please see  this link
https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/overlays.html

Comment: Hi, No I don't want to overlay bit map. I want to show some geojson layers, marker clusters layers and some marker group layers over map. to control there visibility (toggle show/hide) I am unable to use map setting control of 'here api'.

Comment: Would you please share geojson layers what it look like?  If you are talking about map layers, please check this document. https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/map-types.html , Vector https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/vector.html and Raster https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/raster.html

Comment: Issue is with map setting ui, it is not working as it should.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the API, it seems `MapSettingsControl.Options` has

```
layers: {
    label: 'test',
    layer: instance of H.map.layer.Layer
}
```

The error we get when toggling is `InvalidArgumentException` from `DataModel.add` regarding the first argument. I believe this means that on toggle, `DataModel.add` is called and passed the `H.map.Group` that is being set in the `MapSettingsControl`, but the DataModel.add expects a `H.map.layer.Layer` but receives the `H.map.Group`.

I'm not sure if it's possible to simply add a `H.map.Group` in `MapSettingsControl`. I think we have to somehow add the `H.map.Group` as a `provider` for a `H.map.layer.Layer` and add the Layer object to `MapSettingsControl`.

**EDIT**

As for adding cluster. When I try to add a new layer for the cluster, it is grayed out. The cluster provider is created and the ObjectLayer is created as well but I think after you have created the `MapSettingsControl` and defined the variable that will act as the `H.map.layer.Layer`, updating the variable will have no effect on the toggle behaviour.